# Does the LEGO Mos Eisley Cantina Jawa shop have any official backstory?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, lego

The recent LEGO set 75290 Mos Eisley Cantina set includes a pretty sizeable side build of a Jawan junk shop.

Here is a picture from the official LEGO promo photos:

[image]

Does this shop make an appearance in the official movies or lore, or is it an invention of The LEGO Group? It's been a few years since I've watched A New Hope and I don't recall seeing anything like it.

Comment: may find something here: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d5/44/e5/d544e5f30f026fcf8ed5c19dcf21a3ef.jpg

Comment: [This reviewer](https://brickset.com/article/53635/review-75290-mos-eisley-cantina) (who appears to know their SW stuff) says that the additional structures "do not take direct inspiration from any specific buildings"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **JN:** **Does the Jawa shop take inspiration from any specific building during the movie?**
>
> **CS:** **Not specifically, no.** Although I was primarily inspired by the scene in the Special Edition of Ep IV where Luke’s Land speeder goes through a very busy street in Mos Eisley and where you can see a lot of buildings and get a good idea of the Mos Eisley architectural style. The interiors are not based on anything specific, but we figured that a shop run by a Jawa would have a lot of engine pieces, tools, blasters, etc
>
> <sub><sup>[Interview with César Soares, Designer of LEGO Star Wars Mos Eisley Cantina (#75290)](https://www.jedinews.com/lego/articles/interview-with-cesar-soares-designer-of-lego-star-wars-mos-eisley-cantina-75290/)</sup></sub>